# remove documents with array field's size less than 3 in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a mongoDB collection named `col` that has documents that look like this

```
{
  {
    intField:123,
    strField:'hi',
    arrField:[1,2,3]
  },

  {
    intField:12,
    strField:'hello',
    arrField:[1,2,3,4]
  },

  {
    intField:125,
    strField:'hell',
    arrField:[1]
  }
}
```

Now i want to remove documents from collection `col` in which `size` of the array field is less than 2.

So i wrote a query that looks like this

```
db.col.remove({'arrField':{"$size":{"$lt":2}}})
```

Now this query doesnt do anything. i checked with `db.col.find()` and it returns all the documents. Whats wrong with this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/):

> You cannot use $size to find a range of sizes (for example: arrays with more than 1 element).

The docs recommend maintaining a separate size field (so in this case, arrFieldSize) with the count of the items in the array if you want to try this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8):

With MongoDB 2.2+ you can use numeric indexes in condition object keys to do this:

```js
db.col.remove({'arrField.2': {$exists: 0}})
```

This will remove any document that doesn't have at least 3 elements in `arrField`.

Comment: best solution for now, in my case , i dont want to get documents which have subarray length bigger than 24

Comment: This is the cleanest solution imho

Answer (score 4):

Note that for some queries, it may be feasible to just list all the counts you want in or excluded using (n)or conditions.

In your example, the following query will give all documents with less than 2 array entries:

```
db.col.find({
  "$or": [
    { "arrField": {"$exists" => false} },
    { "arrField": {"$size" => 1} },
    { "arrField": {"$size" => 0} }
  ]
})
```

Comment: But as the accepted answer says, you can't range-query $size so this wont work.

Comment: This absolutely works. It's not a native range query, it's just a plain old ORing of all the $size values you are interested in. I.e. instead of saying "give me all documents with arrField $size 0–2", you can ask for "all documents with arrField $size 0, arrField $size 1, or arrField $size 2". Obviously this is only feasible if the range of $size values you are interested in is small, but in those cases it works very well and may be more convenient than adding a arrFieldSize counter or similar.

Comment: Right sorry - my mistake.  If you make an edit I can remove the downvote I gave the answer before.

Comment: Thanks. My original formatting was horrible anyway – so edit I did.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
db.col.remove({$where: "this.arrField.length < 2"})
```