# mongoengine - query how to filter by ListField size

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, mongodb-query

I have the following model:

```
class Like(EmbeddedDocument):
    user = ReferenceField(User,dbref=False)
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow,required=True)
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': False}

class Post(Document):
   name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
   likes = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Like))
```

I would like to filter only Posts with more than 20 likes (ListField size greater than 20). I've tried to query using:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__size_gte=20)
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes_gte=20)
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__gte=20)
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__size_gte=20)
```

None of them work.

But if I use the exact match (ListField size exactly 20 likes) it works:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__size=20)
```

Comments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Far from being the perfect solution, but you can do with a raw mongo query and the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator, for example:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(__raw__={'$where': 'this.likes.length > 20'})
```

Another option, which should work faster, but is less clear in my opinion, is to check whether the 21th element exists:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__21__exists=True)
```

The second option only works if you're using MongoDB 2.2+

Source: Taken from these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongo-db-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1) and applied to MongoEngine.

Comment: This is a good hack. Tks. I´m curious if using ´length´ will not be expensive on the serverside.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit expensive. You're basically evaluating the function (in this case `length > 20`) for each Document.
The `exists` version should be much more efficient...

Comment: From the mongo docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 5):

You can't use $size for a range of values.

From mongo's site:

> $size does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on fields with different 
>   numbers of elements, create a counter field that you increment when you add elements to a field.

This is the link to the related question that led to the answer: [remove documents with array field's size less than 3 in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439860/remove-documents-with-array-fields-size-less-than-3-in-mongodb?rq=1)

This is the mongo page that the previous link linked to that gave the documentation in the block up above:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/#_S_size

Try adding a counter field as suggested in the text block.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any plan to implement this feature?

Comment: There is nothing in the upcoming release notes to indicate that will change, but I don't have any knowledge of development beyond the 2.2.4 release. I imagine the reason has something to do specifically with how $size is implemented under the hood that they so matter of factly don', but I've never looked, so I don't know exactly.